# JSR-303 custom ConstraintValidator in Spring MVC

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement a `@Future` validator for joda time objects.

I followed the implementation for the `@Past` annotation found [here](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2010/05/providing-bean-validation-support-for.html). So far, so good.

Now I am failing at telling spring that I have this new constraint. Is there a way to configure the Spring MVC (other than just `<mvc:annotation-driven />`) to tell him where the validation.xml file is? Or just to directly tell him where my new validator is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I use JSR-303 validation has per se nothing to do with spring. How the file is read depends on your implementation lib of JSR-303. It is most then most likely just a bean.